# Laravel, beanstalkd and multiple databases

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3, beanstalkd, laravel-forge

I have a project in which each client has a unique subdomain and their own database.

I would like to use Laravel's queues for processing jobs and sending notifications. But since the SerializesModels trait only serializes/unserializes the model id, The job is always attempting to retrieve data from the main db, regardless of which client initiates the job.

Is there a way that I can specify a db connection?  If that isn't feasible, I'm open to suggested alternative workflows.

From the Laravel docs:

> Eloquent models will be gracefully serialized and unserialized when the job is processing. If your queued job accepts an Eloquent model in its constructor, only the identifier for the model will be serialized onto the queue. When the job is actually handled, the queue system will automatically re-retrieve the full model instance from the database. It's all totally transparent to your application and prevents issues that can arise from serializing full Eloquent model instances.

Example: So a job is dispatched with the correct order from the OrderController

```
dispatch(new SendEventSignupEmail($order));
```

The order is injected through the constructor in the job class

```
 public function __construct(Order $order)
{
    //
    $this->order = $order;
}
```

It is my understanding that the model id extracted and serialized and send to the handle method where it is unserialized and the model is re-retrieved from the db.

```
public function handle()
{
  Mail::to($this->order)->send(new EventSignup($this->order));
}
```

The problem is that at this point, $this->order is actually a different order (or the job fails) because the serializesModels trait retrieved the model from the default db.

Answer (score 0):

The SerializesModels trait is (in my opinion) a bit unintuitive. As you found, it only serializes the ID, then hits the database to rehydrate the object. However, that trait isn't required in order to serialize models.

Remove the trait and it should serialize the object as a whole, so your job doesn't have to hit the database to get its data.